# rails populate field in model depending on another field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I need to order days by name, I have a table with a field called day_name, its a select so it can only be sunday, monday, etc.

So I am thinking to add another field to my table (day_order) that when somebody enters sunday on day_name it populates day_order with 1, when somebody enters monday in day_name, but I don't know how to populate the day_order depending on the day_name.

There could be another option, that it should be that when somebody picks "sunday" in day_name, store a 1 instead, and change it again when read the table. But I don't know how to do it neither.

So I need help, I was trying to order with an array storing the days in order and then try to make a custom order, but I think it would be easy (and faster) to do it the other way from the model. So I can sort it easily.

PD: I'm looking at the before_save filter in the model

Answer (score 0):

I solved it,

Finally I added an integer day_order field to the timetables table. And made its presence mandatory

```
    validates :day_order, presence: true
```

Then I limited in the model the number that can be added to this field with

```
    def day_order_enum
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    end
```

and next step is doing a before_validation method

```
    before_validation :set_day_order

    def set_day_order
        if self.day_name == "monday"
            self.day_order = 1
        elsif self.day_name == "tuesday"
            self.day_order = 2
        elsif self.day_name == "wednesday"
            self.day_order = 3
        elsif self.day_name == "thursday"
            self.day_order = 4
        elsif self.day_name == "friday"
            self.day_order = 5
        elsif self.day_name == "saturday"
            self.day_order = 6
        end
    end
```

Finally I made a scope ordering the days by the day_order field

```
    scope :day_asc_order, ->{ order('day_order ASC') }
```

And the I used the day_asc_order when listing.

Probably it is not the best way to do it, but it works. If somebody knows a better way to do it and want to share it, I would thank him/her.

PS: I don't need sunday so it's not on the list on purpose ;)